# If $F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ is perfect, how to show F is perfect?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

$E=F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$, which is a finite generated field extension, and if E is perfect, how to show F is perfect?

A field is called perfect if every irreducible polynomial over this field is separable.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What's a perfect field again?

Comment: Every irreducible polynomial over this field is separable.

Comment: This is a good question, in fact it has been asked a couple of times here, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3948762/if-l-k-is-a-finite-field-extension-and-l-is-perfect-then-k-is-perfect?rq=1) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3099199/if-l-mid-k-is-a-finite-extension-of-fields-then-k-is-perfect-iff-l-is-perfect).